# Hide MS VBA screen in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I work in an office where we have a number of amateur Excel "experts", who are constantly trying to "improve" (i.e. shortcut, change the logic, rewrite to make "faster") the spreadsheets. As I work in a very regulated world, where macros need to be approved by the company, the clients, and the regulator, changing the macros is very much a no-no.

One of the issues is that we have is that the people are able to get into the code, even after we have put in password protection to set the sheets to Read Only, and also set a password in the VBA Properties screen. The users seem to be able to bypass the passwords, and get into the main code, without the passwords that have been set.

Is there anything else that can be done to stop them getting into the code? An idea that was mentioned, but I can't find a reference to it was to prevent the VBA screen from opening. Can this be done? Any other advice would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: move your projects into VSTO solutions or compiled DLL functions

Comment: A memo informing them of the consequences of breaching company security policy, particularly if they are employing techniques to bypass the built-in protection features would be one way.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Thanks for your input. Very useful. I will take them under advisement

Comment: @Alex K Good idea, but that has already been tried. Might need to have one fired "pour encourager les autres"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you give your users physical access to a PC, you can't guarantee that your security won't be defeated. The whole industry even says as much:

> If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore

Password protection is at best a deterrent. If your users are already circumventing your protections, then there's nothing you can do to absolutely block them from the VBA, other than removing VBA altogether.

Is is possible to install Office without the VBA capabilities, but then you can't run any Macros whatsoever, so you're probably losing more than you gain in locking it down.

You could try obfuscating your code, but that's not really stopping your users from writing more of their own.

You can, however, use managed add-ins and VSTO, whereby the code is moved out of the Excel workbooks and VBA modules, and into .NET source. The assemblies are deployed and/or installed, and can't easily be changed by users.

Most regulators that I've worked with are aware of the limitations of VBA and password protection, but they're also aware of the business benefits of allowing users to work with the features that Excel and VBA provide. They've usually taken the view that as long as you've implemented reasonable passwords and protections, then any circumvention of those protections is beyond the capability of the typical user.

You have to put reasonable protections in place, and distribute and enforce robust policies and procedures. Yes, you'll get people who violate policy, but you'll have a clear case, should regulators question your approaches.

On the other hand, rather than assuming that some/all of your "experts" are malicious, maybe organize a series of sessions to discuss how things can be improved. You never know, they might have real optimizations that reduce your costs and/or improve your performance and resiliency.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful commentary. I will have to take it under advisement.